# How can I get Record Type, Link and Name of child records from a SOSL search?

Tags: sosl

I am building a small lightening component that on input search it should return account record names alongside contact record names alongside their types if they are account of contact and a link to open the records up in another page. I have written the SOSL search to get the ID but I am lost to how I can get the others from that ID.

```
public with sharing class lwcrecordtypes {
    public lwcrecordtypes() {

    }
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> retrieveContactData(string keySearch){       
        List<List<sObject>> contactAndAccountList = [Find :keySearch IN All Fields RETURNING Contact(Id), Account(Id) ];
        List<String> ids = new List<String>();
        for (List<SObject> sobjs : contactAndAccountList) {
            for (SObject sobj : sobjs) {
              ids.add(sobj.Id);
            }
          }
        return ids;
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is specifically related to SOSL and apex, there is no need to code dump your whole component(s). please specify what is the current behavior of your sosl query, what you have tried and where you are stuck. thanks

Comment: I am trying to get the record name, record url and record type (if it's contact or account) for the fields so I can pass it to the lightening search parameter so that if users search it brings back related records accoeding to the search that are in account or contact objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can just return the values you want directly to your controller:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<List<sObject>> retrieveContactData(string keySearch){       
    return [Find :keySearch IN All Fields RETURNING Contact(Id,Name), Account(Id,Name)];
}
```

The results will include all the information you need, the Id, Name, and type of record (`sobjectType`).

Comment: I did this but on the frontend I cant get the exact data. I am only getting name and object. I am not getting the exact name.

Comment: I get the data now but it seems I cant get record types and the record url link from sosl.